# Shopware 6 Local Plugin Linting

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When creating a Plugin as an extension partner on account.shopware.com the code will run through a static code analysis.

Is there any way to run the code analysis locally?

I could not find anything about that topic in any Shopware documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full [Quality Guideline](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-plugins/) for Shopware6 Plugins (and probably Apps).
The guidline is a bit cluttered in my opinion, so the relevant part for the automatic tests is a bit hidden in it.

[Automatic code reviews with PhpStan and SonarQube](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-plugins/#automatic-code-reviews-with-phpstan-and-sonarqube)  are used, when uploading a Plugin to the Shopware store -> here's the [Test Profile](https://github.com/shopwareLabs/store-plugin-codereview) on GitHub.

Also for administration, Shopware itself is using [Automated code tests with Cypress](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/guidelines/testing/store/quality-guidelines-plugins/#automated-code-tests-with-cypress) for JavaScript. I haven't seen many plugins having those tests. So I don't think it's mandatory (but tests are good thing to do in general).